# Can geo fencing be done in Zoho Creator forms at user level?

Tags: geolocation, geofencing, zoho-deluge

Is there a deluge to either do geo fencing/geo restriction in Zoho creator form at user level or any api/integration to restrict a user to update a field in Zoho form according to his location within a radius for his own login & we are able to define geo locations for different users??

I’m able to fetch geo coordinates in the form & also able to do geo fencing at form level.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get the users geo-coordinates then it should be possible to create an 'on-load' workflow script for the form.   The script should check if the user's geo-location is not in the allowed geo-location.  Then, if the user is not in the allowed geo-location, set each field in the form to either disabled or hidden.  It should also be possible to set an `alert` message to inform the user of the geo-location constraint.